# Relating $l(A),l(B)$ and $l(A+B)$ for Weil divisors on a smooth projective curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over an Algebraically closed field $k$. Let $k(X)$ denote its function field.

If $A, B$ are Weil divisors on $X$ such that $A$ is effective (i.e. $A\ge 0$) , then is there any (in)equality between $l(A+B)$ and $ l(B)+l(A)$ ?

Here, for a Weil divisor $D$ on $X$, by $l(D)$ we denote the $k$-vector space dimension of the Riemann-Roch space $\mathcal L(D):=\{f\in k(X)^*: D+ div(f)\ge 0\}\cup \{0\}$.

Update: For a divisor $D$ on $X$, the complete linear system  $|D|$ be the collection of all effective divisors which are linearly equivalent with $D$. $|D|$ can be given the structure of a projective space by identifying it with $(\mathcal L(D)\setminus \{0\})/k^*$  and by that structure, $\dim |D|=l(D)-1$. Now it is known (Hartshorne, Chapter IV, Lemma 5.5) that if $D,E$ are both effective divisors, then $\dim |D|+\dim |E|\le \dim |D+E|$ i.e. $l(D)+l(E)\le l(D+E)+1$ . What I'm basically asking is that if something similar holds if we assume only one of tgr divisors is effective...

Comment: I have the impression that the map $$\begin{align*}\mathcal{L}(A)\otimes_k \mathcal{L}(B)&\longrightarrow \mathcal{L}(A+B) \\f\otimes g &\longmapsto fg\end{align*}$$
should be injective (at least in a lot of cases, for example for $X=\mathbb{P}^1$ and $A,B$ of positive degree I think it should be true) and so it makes more sense to have something like $l(A)\cdot l(B)\leq l(A+B)$.

Comment: @nowheredense No this is false, even on $X=\mathbb{P}^1$ : take $A=B=1[0]+1[\infty]$ then $l(A)=l(B)=3$ and $l(A+B)=5$. Actually $\mathcal{L}(A)$ is spanned by $1,z,\frac{1}{z}$. You have an element in the kernel of the multiplication map by taking for instance $1\otimes z-z\otimes 1$.

Comment: aah it's true, in $\mathbb{P}^1$ by Riemann-Roch we have $l(A)=\deg(A)+1$ for any $A$ of positive degree so it doesn't make sense what I said. Thanks for the correction

Comment: @Roland , nowhere dense: Please see the edited Question for updates